# pandas TimedeltaIndex.join does not take sort arg

Tags: python, pandas, join

The latest pandas 0.20.2 TimedeltaIndex.join method does not take 'sort=...' kwarg, so that it cannot be used as a join index as required in pandas/core/reshape/merge.py line 722. Here's how to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tx = pd.timedelta_range('09:30:00', '10:00:00', freq='30s')
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(tx), 3), index=tx, columns=['a','b','c'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(tx), 2), index=tx, columns=['d','e'])
df0.join(df1)
```

The exception is thrown at:

> ```
> /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.pyc in _get_join_info(self)
>
> 720             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \
> 721                 left_ax.join(right_ax, how=self.how, return_indexers=True,
> --> 722                              sort=self.sort)
> 723         elif self.right_index and self.how == 'left':
> 724             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \
>
> TypeError: join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'
> ```

Version 0.19.2 works ok.
Is this a bug or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.  There is an issue report ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16541)) and a Pull Request that is being worked on ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/16586)) with the hope to complete for [0.20.3](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/milestone/51)

***Update:***

The fix made it into ([0.20.3](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/milestone/51?closed=1))

Comment: Seems to be fixed in pandas 0.20.3